# elixir test fails with "Reason: already started"

Tags: testing, elixir

I'm currently working on my first big elixir project and wanted to properly utilize testing this time.
However, if I add my Modules to the "normal" supervisor, i cannot start them again with `start_supervised!` and all tests fail with `Reason: already started: #PID<0.144.0>`

Here is my code:

(application.ex)

```
    defmodule Websocks.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      {Websocks.PoolSupervisor, []},
      {Websocks.PoolHandler, %{}}
      # {Websocks.Worker, arg}
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Websocks.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Some of my tests:

```
defmodule PoolHandlerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  alias Websocks.PoolHandler
  doctest PoolHandler

  setup do
    start_supervised!({PoolHandler, %{}})
    %{}
  end

  test "adding two pools and checking if they are there" do
    assert PoolHandler.add(:first) == :ok
    assert PoolHandler.add(:second) == :ok
    assert PoolHandler.get_pools() == {:ok,%{:first => nil, :second => nil}}
  end
```

and the pool handler:

```
defmodule Websocks.PoolHandler do
  use GenServer

  # Client
  def start_link(default) when is_map(default) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, default, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  # Server (callbacks)

  @impl true
  def init(arg) do
    {:ok, arg}
  end
end
```

(I cut out the stuff i think is not necessary, but the complete code is on github here: [github](https://github.com/MrSoUndso/WebSocks))

Thanks in advance for any help i get!

Comment: I don't think you need to start things for tests that are listed in `application.ex` -- as far as I know, everything in `application.ex` is started when you do your test run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Everett mentioned in the comment - your application will already be started for you when you `mix test`, so there is no need to start your `GenServers` again. It seems like you're interacting with the global instance in your test, so if that's what you want, then it should just work.

However, if you'd like to start a separate instance just for your test, you need to start an unnamed one. For example, you could add an optional pid argument to your wrapper functions:

```elixir
defmodule Websocks.PoolHandler do

  # ...

  def add(server \\ __MODULE__, value) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:add, value})
  end

  # ...

end
```

Then, instead of using using `start_supervised!` like you do, you can start an unnamed instance in your `setup` and use it in your tests like so:

```elixir
setup do
  {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(PoolHandler, %{})
  {:ok, %{handler: pid}}
end

test "adding two pools and checking if they are there", %{handler: handler} do
  PoolHandler.add(handler, :first)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: “you need to start an unnamed one”—technically, it might be named, just the name must differ from anything already registered.